# Are there more specific types for string?

Tags: types, language-agnostic

This is a very soft question and not related to a concrete problem. I'm mostly curious if the thing i want is actually "a thing" and if it has a name. I think it would be "**nominal subtypes of string**".

When writing code strings are used for all kinds of proposes, for example a SQL query, a path to a local file, a piece of code, a phone number, an email address, a physical mail address or simple a user name.

While it makes sense that they are all represented as strings in memory, i think there should be a way to specify the type further.

For example: The string "`info@Jane.Doe`" can be a valid URL, a valid email-address, a local file or simply a username, while all are represented by the same data, the meaning changes based on the type.

The same way the bits in memory have different meaning if they are interpreted as a floating point number, a integer or a byte array.

How can this be solved? Does any programming language has this already build in?

---

Here are some ways i thought of/found to solve this:

- add some prefix to the actual value, if possible:

  - use [URI schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes), like `http://`, `https://` for web urls, `tel:` for telephone numbers, `mailto` for emails, `file://` for local files and enforce that they are present.
  - for code something like [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) or add the language as a comment, for example `String query = "/*SQL*/ SELECT * FROM [users] ... ;"`
- add a prefix or a suffix to the variable names,

  - for example `optionalContact_POSTADDRESS` to indicate a database column with a string to address an envelope
  - or `String SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM [users] ... "`
- Use Wrapper objects that add little to no functionality.

  - For example a class that has only a single property of type String and is only used for type evaluation `SQL_Query query = new SQL_Query("SELECT * FROM [users] ... ");`
- some minor support for specific combinations

  - php code to be executed is enclosed `<?php` `?>` inside of html and like wise html code to be outputted is enclosed in `?>` `<?php` inside of php code, but i think that is mostly for technical reasons
  - markdown allow to specify what syntax highlighting to be used ```` ```language↲first line of code... ``` ````
  - JS/ECMAscript allows Regular Expressions [to use `/` as delimiters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), but that's mostly a short hand for creating an RegEx object `/abc/ == new RegEx("abc")`
  - JS/ECMAscript has Tagged Templates they look promising, but they are just syntactic sugar for a function call to customize the templating engine.
  - Some IDEs can detect Strings of a specific language and add syntax highlighting, it's called "**language injection**", JavaScript and CSS in a HTML file (via the script and style tags) is very common,  but there more universal approaches using comments (`# language=<language_ID>` in the line before)
  - Typescript allows some very narrow type constraint, but is limited to duck typing, see my first example, you can't catch data that is coincidentally valid in another format.

Comment: Context is given at the application level, not within memory. That said, there is nothing to stop you from creating your own types that are a subset of `string` in languages that support custom type definitions or OOP. This would still not affect how the string is stored in memory. A string is just textual data that is generally intended for visual purposes only. "How can this be solved?" - Creating your own types that restrict a string to represent a more specific entity, such as a URL, email address, regex, etc is perfectly fine and it can be a great practice for developers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of "scope", or "responsibility", or in which "domain" or under which circumstances the current
definition of a "string" is applicable/valid.

E.g.

- The CPU doesn't know "strings", it just moves bits around, even if they represent text characters.
- A Text- or Drawing-software doesn't know "strings", even though a "string" type is used in their code.
- A programming language knows "strings", because it needs them to do what it does.

#### generic types

The programming language only defines what it needs to do it's work.

Why should a programming language care if it's an e-mail or a user name ?
That information is not necessary to pass arguments, iterate characters or allocate memory. It is only necessary to
e.g. keep a user input valid for a data base, but that's outside of the responsibility of the programming language.

A programming language may define a data type "string" as a sequence of bytes or a sequence of Unicode characters, and then **that's all it is**.

A datatype defined in some area, like a programming language, needs to be defined to be useful for everything that is supposed
to be done **in this area**. Anything that is specific to some **specific use case** should be defined outside this programming language.

There might be millions of specific formats, like [IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) (v4 and v6), [ISBN numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISBN), [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), ..., and many more,
which can not all be covered by one definition.

#### specific types

More specific types should be focused only on a specific area and also be defined there.

If your example `"info@Jane.Doe"` is an e-mail address or a just a user name should be defined and
determined by the software that is built *with using* the programming language, but not *by* the programming language.

E.g. you may define your own type system, i.e. you define what a type itself *is*. E.g. your type system could support a data structure:

```
myInternalValue = {
  type: Types.UserName,
  value: "info@Jane.Doe",
}
```

You functions and validators that use this kind of type need to be able to handle this data structure.

#### String parsing / interpretation

Your examples `<?php`, `language ...` and syntax highlighting work because a high level software (not a programming language)
interprets the strings in a very specific way. This is done by a part of a software that is called [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).
An example of a simple parser is [simple-markdown](https://github.com/Khan/perseus/tree/main/packages/simple-markdown).